# Javascript Closure / Scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I am learning about closure and scope, and came across this example. I am confused as to why `humansMoney` continues to decrement every time the function is invoked, yet it seems to me that it should be reset to 100 on every invocation.

The instructor at one point mentioned that by calling `carl()`, we are only calling the inner function, not the outer function. I simply do not understand this.... `carl()` is calling `human()`, so why would `humansMoney` not get reset to 100?

Can someone please explain (like I'm 5) why this phenomenon is occurring? I would very much appreciate any advice on this.

Thank you so much.

```
function human() {
    var humansMoney = 100;

    function cat() {
        humansMoney--;
        console.log('human: ' + humansMoney);
        var catsMoney = 100;
        console.log('cat: ' + catsMoney);
    }
    return cat;
}

var carl = human();

carl(); // humansMoney = 99, catsMoney = 100
carl(); // humansMoney = 98, catsMoney = 100
carl(); // humansMoney = 97, catsMoney = 100
carl(); // humansMoney = 96, catsMoney = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

`var humansMoney = 100;` only runs when you call the `human` function.

You only do that once.

Every other time, you call the `carl` function, which is the returned `cat` function.

---

Re edit.

> carl() is calling human()

No, it isn't.

It is calling the value of `carl`, which is the **return value** of the expression `human()`. That's the cat function.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of calling the function `human` is essentially the definition of the inner function `cat`, with a closure containing a reference to the variable `humansMoney`.  That's why you can invoke `carl` like so `carl()`.  Every time you call `carl()`, you're actually calling `cat` but with the stored and persisting value of `humansMoney` being stored from one invocation to the next.

If you were to invoke `human` again, assigning it to a new variable, for example `var jim = human()`, you would then have a new closure where `humansMoney` was 100.  Now every time you call `jim()`, you'll decrement Jim's money.